# Showing that the span of elementary vectors is $F^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove this question from Friedberg's Linear Algebra[image]

I've "mostly" shown that $span(\{e_1, \ldots e_j\}) \subseteq F^n$. I'm not sure if it's adequate. Here is what I have thus far:

Proof. Supposed $e_j \in F^n$ and $e_j$ has entries

$$(e_j)_i = 0 \text{   if } \neq j$$
$$(e_j)_i = 1 \text{   if } = j$$
$$\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$$

Suppose $x \in span(\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\})$. Then, by definition of span, $x = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} c_j e_j$. Now, each $ce_j$ has entries

$$(c_j e_j)_i = c_j (e_j)_i$$ by definition of scalar multiplication of vectors. Then, by definition of our elementary vector,

$$c_j(e_j)_i = c_j \text{   if } i = j$$
$$c_j(e_J)_i = 0 \text{   if } i \neq j$$

*This part I'm not so sure about. I'm unsure of how to make the connection between this point of my proof and the next*: So by definition of vector addition, $x$ has entries $(x)_i = c_i$ because we sum from $j = 1$ to $n$, so if any particular summed vectors will never have the same index of summation. Thus, because $c_i \in F$, $x \in F_n$, so $span(\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}) \subseteq F_n$

Then, for the reverse I'm completely lost.

Suppose $x \in F^n$. Then $x$ has entries

$$(x)_i = c_i \in F$$

My idea is to simply say

$$(x)_i = c_i + 0 + \cdots + 0$$
where I have $n - 1$ $0's$, but I don't know how to fllow up from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $S$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $V$, in particular, $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is a subset of $V$. Now, take $V = \textsf{F}^n$ and $S = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$.
- Pick an arbitrary element of $\textsf{F}^n$, let's say, $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$. In order to prove that $x$ is in $\operatorname{span} (\{e_1,\dots,e_n\})$, $x$ must be a linear combination of the vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$, but this is easy, just see:

$$x = x_1e_1 + \cdots + x_ne_n.$$

Comment: Is this really all I have to do? Is the first part fine? The text directly after the italicized portion I mean. I don't really have a good sense for proof writing because I've only had one proof-based course and I never had a good understanding of how to create a good argument